# Get terminal service profile path from AD user in code

Tags: c#, active-directory

I'm trying to read the terminal service profile path for a selected AD user using the following code snip.

```
...
using System.DirectoryServices;
using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;
... 
try 
{
   Debug.WriteLine("Looking for: " + DisplayName);
   DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(strLDAP, strUserName, strPassword);
   DirectorySearcher Searcher = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
   Searcher.Filter = "(displayName="+ DisplayName +")";
   SearchResult result = Searcher.FindOne();     
   DirectoryEntry found = result.GetDirectoryEntry();

   // tell if we found the right user
   Debug.WriteLine(found.Properties["mail"][0].ToString());

   // tell what the current terminal services profile path is
   Debug.WriteLine(found.InvokeGet("TerminalServicesProfilePath").ToString()); 
}
catch (DirectoryServicesComException e)
{
  Debug.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
}
```

Sadly I get the following error when I do an `InvokeGet`:

> ... System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in System.DirectoryServices.dll
>   System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80020006): Unknown name. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020006 (DISP_E_UNKNOWNNAME))

I'm bumped here..
I know the parameter `TerminalServicesProfilePath` is in AD in a `"userParameter"` hash.
And invoking it should get something readable.

What am I doing wrong?

Side note: the AD resides on a 2003 level domain.

Comment: Is there some reason you're not using found.Properties["TerminalServicesProfilePath"]?

Comment: I tried to do `found.Properties["TerminalServicesProfilePath"]` which doesn't work.

Comment: try doing `Searcher.PropertiesToLoad.Add("TerminalServicesProfilePath");` right before the `FindOne()` call then use `found.Properties["TerminalServicesProfilePath"]`

Comment: I have not yet found the answer, but it has to do with a missing library on your system.  I have Windows 7 64 bit, and if I am careful to use the 64 bit powershell I can InvokeGet on the TerminalServicesProfilePath, but if I use the 32bit version I cannot.  I know that the InvokeGet is required to read the values, because they are not really AD attributes, and there is a library that implements this feature to the system's native ADSI service provider.  I'm hoping to find the missing dependency soon...

Comment: you can try to use       found.RefreshCache(new[] { "TerminalServicesProfilePath" });    before running InvokeGet().